# I want inactive touchstart after each swipe for 1 second and after 1 second touchstart active

Tags: javascript

I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429913/how-to-use-jquery-swipe-without-any-library) of the stackoverflow for write swiping left/right in my project but now I want inactive touchstart after each swipe for 1 second and after 1 second touchstart active.In below only algorithm that came to my mind, but it does not work well.

```
var drag = true;
function touchStart(event, passedName){
  if(!drag){
    // document.removeEventListener('touchstart', touchStart, false);
    return;
  }
  else{
    drag = false
  }
  // do for touchstart
  setTimeout(function(){
    drag = true;
  }, 1000);
}
```

and I add this code in touchMove:

```
function touchMove(event){
  ul.style.left = event.touches[0].pageX - x + 'px';// touchstart inactive but element still moving
}
```

Comment: "doesnt work well" ?

Answer (score 1):

You also have to block `touchMove`:

```
 var dragging = false, blocked = false;

 function touchStart(event, passedName){
   if(blocked) return;
   blocked = true;
   setTimeout(() => blocked = false, 1000);

   dragging = true;
 }

 function touchEnd(event) { dragging = false; }

 function touchMove(event) {
    if(!dragging) return;
    //...
  }
```